# GNS3 - Telnet issue

Tags: telnet, router

I have created the following Network in GNS3 [GNS3 Simple Network Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGqAM.png). 
Let me explain the SetUp:

1. The internet cloud **Cloud 1** is connected to my **LAN** and not **loopback**.
2. R1 routers' F0/0 is getting the IP from DHCP, to which i can telnet and ping from any remote host in my LAN.
3. R1 also configured with SNMP access (public community string)
4. The IP for R1 routers' F0/1 interface is manually configured. This interface i can ping from any remote host on my LAN however Telnet fails.
5. R2 routers' F0/0 ip is manully configured. The situation is same here, where i am able to ping however telnet is failing. All the configuration is same between R1 and R2.

Just mentioning again, all the interfaces are ping-able from any Remote Host in the same LAN, however only R1's F0/0 is telnet-able (hope that is a word)

Is there some configuration change that i can do to get telnet access to all the interfaces?

Comment: enable telnet on R2 by using the `line vty 0 4` and setting a password. Telnet won't work if you don't have a password set.

Comment: Yes, I am aware telnet won't work without password being set. I have tried setting password but I still get "connection refused".  But it works for R1 over F0/0